# In writing, how to politely tell someone not to repeat something?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

Preface: This question applies only to writing, which lacks the benefits of  nonverbal communication which would resolve this problem.

Example: Your lawyer remembers your remembrance that she cannot do something (eg: She can advise only on real estate law, and not trust law in which she is inexperienced.). However, her excessive caution causes her to keep reminding you redundantly. How do you most tactfully inform her that she need not remind you? My attempts below all sound impolite.

> 1. Please do not repeat it.
>      Problem: This sounds too authoritative, even with 'please'.
> 2. Please, (there is) no need to repeat it.
>      Problem: This sounds as though her reminders have dispirited and fatigued you.
> 3. Please do not worry about repeating it.
>      Problem: My own experiences [attest](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Attest+this+as+true%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=EojTVZ-3MsefNoynhfAK#q=%22Attest+it+true%22&tbm=bks&start=0) and prove this ineffective; the other parties rebut me by insisting that they are not 'worried', and then repeat it anyways to my annoyance.

Comment: Is this the only piece of information you're trying to convey to the lawyer, or is there some other communication (not necessarily related to the issue of which you are asking)?

Comment: So the lawyer is saying that s/he can't do something? Or is the lawyer saying that the client can't do something?

Comment: @CRABOLO You are right that the lawyer's saying that s/he can't do something. For example, the client may ask the lawyer about trust law when the lawyer is inexperienced in it.

Comment: @VictorBazarov You are right that I am only trying to convey to the lawyer, this request to stop repetition. Does this answer your question? I am unsure of the meaning of `some other communication`.

Comment: Are you saying that the lawyer keeps reminding you "I can't do X" but that your business is actually about "Y" and that there's no reason to bring "X" into it? Or is there a legal relationship between "X" and "Y" (in which case it might be necessary to mention in every communication)?

Comment: @user2338816 No, no deep relationship between X and Y, but X and Y may be superficially related. In my example above, X and Y are law, yes, but completely separate subfields. So you are right that `the lawyer keeps reminding you "I can't do X" but that your business is actually about "Y" and that there's no reason to bring "X" into it`.

Comment: The fact that the lawyer (or whoever) keeps repeating the warning implies to me that you keep straying onto that topic. Particularly with legal issues, a lawyer will want to reiterate that an answer outside their practice area can not be relied upon *legally*.

Comment: Repetition, especially in writings, implies to me that there should be no lasting physical evidence. Some future misfeasance/malfeasance action might be decided on a single letter that did not contain the words. Probable self-preservation of a conscientious lawyer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

> Keeping in mind that you are unable *[whatever she says she cannot do]*, let us focus on the other important aspects of the case.

Essentially you now tell *her* whatever it is, and thus give her a hint that she doesn't need to do that.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

> *"Yes, I remember that from the last time you told me."*

You're not exactly telling the person to stop (which is where the rudeness comes in), but you're conveying the sentiment that the information doesn't need to be repeated anymore.

Comment: Not sure about those up-ticks... The answer given mostly explains how to respond *verbally* to something that was just repeated the umpteenth time.  What about in writing?  How to make it "a pre-emptive *'shoosh'*" (like Dr.Evil said)?

Comment: @Victor - The answer I've given here *is* the way I would write it, given the situation described by the O.P. In fact, I think this is a polite way to handle this in written form, but I think it would be borderline rude to say this aloud in the situation you describe.

Comment: My concern is more with the "Yes", which rarely has its place in written communication, and thus suggests more of a verbal reply... No matter.

Comment: @Victor - "Yes" is an affirmative word, and affirmative words can help offset the negative tone of a remark. I agree that it's an uncommon use, but I think it's a permissible one.

Answer (score 1):

In the hope that this phrase may be useful for the OP and anyone who is in a similar situation, I'd like to suggest this phrase:

> I'm sorry that you had to repeat that again.